# Why is my jquery selector ignored?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jquery snippet below I want to replace some html in each element that fits the selector `a.thumbs` (it gets a thumbnail from youtube).

The problem is that it's not working as I expected. If all `a` elements on the page has the class "thumbs" it works fine (each `a` element is given my html). But if there is one or more `a` elements that has another class, than that element gets the html, and not the `a` element with the class thumbs.

I cannot figure out why. Please help :-). I  must have misunderstood how .each() works.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Youtube
        var $youtube;
        var video_id;
        $("a.thumbs").each(function (index, value){
            $youtube = $('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com"], a[href^="http://youtu.be"], a[href^="http://youtube.com"]');
            video_id = $youtube[index].href.split('v=')[1];
            console.log(video_id);
            $youtube[index].innerHTML = '<div class=\"youtube_container\"><div class=\"youtube_thumb image\"><img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.concat(video_id).concat('/1.jpg\"></div><div class=\"youtube_overlay image\"><img src=\"/sites/all/themes/mycompany/images/video-overlay.png\"></div></div>');
        });
    });
});
```

Edited:
Thanks very much for the suggestions. None of them worked though, but I am beginning to understand better after your remarks. So here's an example of the html. The goal is to fetch and show the youtube thumbnail in html that only contains a simple link to the youtube video. So this html:

```
<p><a class="thumbs" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vvxxxx123">random text</a></p>
```

is supposed to turn into this:

```
<a class="thumbs" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vvxxxx123">
<div class="youtube_container">
<div class="youtube_thumb image">
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Vvxxxx123/1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="youtube_overlay image">
<img src="/sites/all/themes/mycompany/images/video-overlay.png">
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

My code works if there is only one link or if all links have the same thumbs class.

Sorry about this lengthy question :-), but i finally got to work thanks to your suggestions. This is the final working code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Youtube

        $('a.thumbs[href^="http://www.youtube.com"], a.thumbs[href^="http://youtu.be"],a.thumbs[href^="http://youtube.com"]').each(function (index, value){
            console.log(value);
            var video_id = this.href.split('v=')[1];
            console.log(video_id);
            this.innerHTML = '<div class=\"youtube_container\"><div class=\"youtube_thumb image\"><img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.concat(video_id).concat('/1.jpg\"></div><div class=\"youtube_overlay image\"><img src=\"/sites/all/themes/mycompany/images/video-overlay.png\"></div></div>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$youtube = $('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com"], a[href^="http://youtu.be"], a[href^="http://youtube.com"]');` will return the same every time!

Comment: Show your HTML too...

Comment: I'm still a little shaky on *what exactly* you're trying to accomplish, but I think the reason you're selecting the wrong elements by mistake is because the `$youtube` variable has almost *nothing* to do with the `a.thumbs` in your code

Comment: Could you please explain why the answer provided by me below did not work for you

Comment: Hello. I am very grateful for all the suggestions. Your code gave me a blank console and didn't execute. Maybe it's because I am doing this in a Drupal environment. Or if it could be something with the pattern? Anyway, my problem is solved. Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the elements in thumbs selector.
You can try this:

```
$('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com"], a[href^="http://youtu.be"],a[href^="http://youtube.com"]').each(function (index, value){
    video_id = this.href;
    console.log(video_id);
    this.innerHTML = '<div class=\"youtube_container\"><div class=\"youtube_thumb image\"><img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.concat(video_id).concat('/1.jpg\"></div><div class=\"youtube_overlay image\"><img src=\"/sites/all/themes/nordtec/images/video-overlay.png\"></div></div>');
});
```

Comment: I didn't get your code to work at first, but after a few changes it did! Thanks a lot for your suggestion! See the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Hope it solves. If it doesn't do comment your requirement which was not satisfied by the below code snippet.

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var video_id;
                var valid_links = "http://www.youtube.com|http://youtu.be\http://youtube.com";
                $("a.thumbs").each(function (index, value) {
                    var re = new RegExp(valid_links, 'g');
                    if ($(value).attr('href').match(re))
                    {
                        video_id = $(value).attr('href').split('v=')[1];
                        console.log(video_id);
                        $(value).html('<div class=\"youtube_container\"><div class=\"youtube_thumb image\"><img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.concat(video_id).concat('/1.jpg\"></div><div class=\"youtube_overlay image\"><img src=\"/sites/all/themes/nordtec/images/video-overlay.png\"></div></div>'));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```